# How to put 3 columns in "Featured Products" module in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7

My problem is this: I put the featured products in the index page, but this put the products in 2 columns and it leaves a blank space to the right and I do not like it.

How can I put more columns? I desire three columns.

The weird thing is that inside of a category, the products are put in 3 columns. The index page and the category page have the same layout and for this reason I do not understrand what happen with this.

I use 1.7.1.2 version.

[image: Index page with blank space on the right]

[image: Category pages with products in 3 columns (perfect)]

Answer (score 0):

How to add two column layout in prestashop 1.7 (moble Or web)
If you want to display two column in mobile screen - prestashop 1.7.6
public_html/www.yourwebsitefoldername.com/themes/classic/assets/css/custom .css

@media (max-width: 767px){
.products .product-miniature {width: 48%!important; float: left !important;}

```
.thumbnail-container {width: 156px !important;}
.product-description {width:152px !important;}
.thumbnail-container {height:267px !important;}
```

}[image]

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if you resolved your question but the answer is:
In website/theme/classic/assets/css/theme.css

```
#products .products, .featured-products .products, .product-accessories 
.products, .product-miniature .products {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: center; <------------------- is center
}
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Maybe the next time using Prestashop, I can resolve the problem :)

Comment: this solution only center the "row". The question was about putting 3 products per row